# Where is boundedness used in proving Cauchy sequences are convergent? Completeness axiom?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Ross - Elementary Analysis

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Where is boundedness used in the proof? Is it for the completeness axiom?

Comment: This is toooooooo long. Try to condense stuff in one fifth, or so, of your present post. What do you want: to prove Cauchy (Real, I presume) sequences are bounded, or something else?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Edited. I want to know where boundedness is used in the proof that Cauchy sequences are convergent

Answer (score 2):

"$\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$" does not imply that the sequence $a_n$ converges. For instance, the sequence $a_n=n$ in $\Bbb R$ is not convergent, though $\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n=+\infty$. Similarly for $a_n=-n$. It does for bounded sequences. (and for an unbounded sequence in $\Bbb R$ you can actually prove that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=+\infty$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=-\infty$)

Comment: But in the book, $\lim s_n$ can be $\infty$. It was initially in the post, but I edited that out after @DonAntonio's comment

Comment: I am 99.99999% sure that, int this context, the author did not mean to allow a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\infty$ to be called "convergent".

Comment: G. Sassatelli, [?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tWOKt.png)

Comment: As far as I know, in real analysis, the term "convergent" is consistently used for sequences $a_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists finite, because of several reasons. The notation $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\pm \infty$ remains in use for convenience, but those sequences are said to "diverge to infinty".

Comment: So the book is wrong to say Theorem 10.7 holds without boundedness assumption?

Comment: No. Theorem $10.7$ says that $\lim_n a_n$ exists as an extended real number (i.e. in $\Bbb R\cup \{\pm\infty\}$) if and only if $\limsup_n a_n=\liminf_n a_n$, in which case it coincides with them. This is undoubtedly true. The boundedness of the sequence comes into play in order to guarantee that said quantities are finite (i.e. that the sequence is "convergent"). Actually, boundedness is necessary too, because unbounded sequences turn out to either have $\limsup=+\infty$ or $\liminf =-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

The boundedness of the sequence ensures that $v_N$ and $u_N$ are real numbers and not $\pm \infty.$ If the sequence were unbounded we would have to replace $\epsilon$ with $\infty$ in the inequalities, and the last line would be $\lim \sup s_n\leq \lim \inf s_n+\infty,$ which may be true, but is useless.

Comment: So boundedness is implicit in the part about the completeness axiom? I mean because of boundedness, the completeness axiom applies?

Comment: As the text says the completeness ensures that the inf and sup, of a non-empty bounded set, do exist within the  reals. Compare it to the rational numbers, where a  Cauchy sequence is bounded but  it may fail to have a sup or inf within the rationals.